# Как конвертировать Response в String

Tags: android, строки, конвертация, okhttp

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, data_params.toString());
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Log.v("TAG", call.request().body().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            Log.v("TAG", response.body().string());
        }
```

Как можно конвертировать `response.body().string()` например `String res = response.body().string();`. Мне нужен просто возвращаемый ответ respons в строковом виде, без классов и интерфейсов. Спасибо

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема? Так как  CallBack у вас не дженерализован, то response.body() вернет объект типа Object. Вызовите на нем метод toString()

Comment: @Роман Данилов, Можете в ответе примером привести? То как я выше указал, у меня вызывает ошибку

Comment: response.body().toString()

Comment: response.body().toString() возвращает вот это -
 okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@60d39a5

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал вам использовать библиотеку retrofit2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем за помощь, вопрос реши следующим образом!

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, data_params.toString());
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(body)
        .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        Log.v("TAG", call.request().body().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        //Исправил здесь
        String responseString = response.body().string();
    }
```

В принципе в коде никакой ошибки не было, погуглив нашел, оказывается метод `response.body().string()` можно вызвать лишь раз! На второй раз и более раз вызывает ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Ответ в виде строки возвращает метод `ResponseBody#string()`. А вы вызываете реализацию метода `toString` у объекта класса `ResponseBody`. Т.е. вам надо так:

```
String responseString = response.body().string();
```

Comment: Происходит ошибка и приложение закрывается((

Comment: @АлишерИсмоилов, без логов ошибки мы с вами можем часами гадать в чём дело. А вот если вы её приведёте в вопросе - скорее всего за пару минут решим проблему.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
Process: us.ethnicmedia.resonanceradio, PID: 32253
java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:377)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:371)
at okhttp3.internal.Util.bomAwareCharset(Util.java:412)
at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:173)
at us.ethnicmedia.resonanceradio.VoteActivity$3.onResponse(VoteActivity.java:254)
at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос логи и побольше. Тут не всё. Не надо в комменты